# Android Imagebutton change Image OnClick

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

I just added a new `drawable` folder under `res` folder. In the `drawable` folder, i copied the `ic_launcher.png` file from `drawable-hdpi` folder.
I wanna change the standard `ImageButton` image through the new one when i press the button. I wrote some code, but when i start the app, it crashes.

```
Button imgButton; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.imgButton).setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);      
}

View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
};
```

EDIT: I changed to this, and this also not works.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
}


View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
};
```

EDIT 2: THIS WORKS. Thanks to all.

```
ImageButton button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
}


View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
};
```

Comment: You should paste here your error from logcat.

Comment: NullpointerException coz imgButton is null ... you can cast View v to Button or set imgButton after setContentView ...

Comment: Your edit is my answer, and that works!

Comment: The only way this is not working, is if your id is NOT "imgButton" (R.id.imgButton).

Comment: How can I set it to a different image when not clicked.

Answer (score 70):

This misled me a bit - it should be `setImageResource` instead of `setBackgroundResource` :) !!

The following works fine :

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);       
 btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.actions_record);
```

while when using the `setBackgroundResource` the actual imagebutton's image 
stays while the background image is changed which leads to a ugly looking imageButton object

Thanks.

Comment: Correct;  doing the `setBackgroundResource` seems to stretch the image to fit the button so it will look distorted.

Answer (score 16):

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/image_btn_src" ... />
```

image_btn_src.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 10):

That is because imgButton is null.
Try this instead:

```
findViewById(R.id.imgButton).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
```

or much easier to read:

```
imgButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
imgButton.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
```

then in onClick: `imgButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);`

Comment: findViewById(R.id.imgButton).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); Ha... this worked. When i start it, it has the new image. Then i don't understand, why the code above is not working in the onClick?

Comment: It doesn't work because you have Button imgButton; declared.. but you don't initiate it a view, that's why. When using findViewById(...) you get the view of the Button (Button in this case), therefore it works.

Comment: Look at my answer mate, I put it there for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it right in your XML file:

```
android:onClick="@drawable/ic_action_search"
```

Comment: OK, but what is, when i click the button again, i want the old image. Like a toggle button.

Comment: but doing this doesnt change the image rather crashes the activity with a log  **' java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method res/drawable-hdpi/menu_mission_touch.png(View) in the activity class com.test.MainMenu for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'menu_mission'
'**

Comment: it´s not possible!

Answer (score 3):

To switch between different images when the ImageButton is clicked I used a boolean like this:

```
ImageButton imageButton;
boolean buttonOn;

imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (!buttonOn) {
             buttonOn = true;
             imageButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_is_on)); 
         } else {
             buttonOn = false;
             imageButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_is_off));
         }
     }
});
```

Comment: hello...suppose im performing this one activity.user click to glow image... what if user goes from one activity to another and again coming back to activity one will the button remain as glow?

Comment: @Wini only if you will pass your button status to another activity and then retrieve it when you are back to this activity

Answer (score 2):

You have assing button to your `imgButton` variable:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
    imgButton.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        imgButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    }
```

Using set Background image resource will chanage the background of the button