# ImageButton change src

Tags: android, imagebutton

Change the ImageButton src

Here is the xml for the tag:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/infobutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/edit"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
```

This is what im doing to the button when it get pressed

```
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.save);
```

The ImageButton before pressed

[image]

Image after press:

[image]

I want the button to only have the save Picture and it beeing fitCenter
and why doesnt the other src get replaced With the New src?

Comment: in xml you are setting source(Foreground) but on button press you are setting background. thats why

Comment: instead of `android:src="@drawable/edit"` try using `android:background="@drawable/edit"` in your `xml`

Comment: "setImageResource" instead of "setBackgroundResource"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android Imagebutton change Image OnClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249495/android-imagebutton-change-image-onclick)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `android:src` and `android:background` is the different attributes. 
You should use

```
button.setImageResource(R.drawable.save);
```

Comment: Agree. @KimVu you are trying to change different attibutes and for this you have two images

Comment: Haha didn't realy think that only changed the background and not Source. Thanks!

Comment: I was Just 3 minutes late

Answer (score 1):

your code is trying to change the background of the button. not its image. Those are two different things

```
((ImageButton) view).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon2);
```